# css: div height flexible to reach the bottom of the screen with some margin

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a two-column page using twitter bootstrap responsive classes:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-7">
      some article here
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-5">
      google map here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The left part will contain an article that may be long enough to exceed the height of the screen, and it will have its own scrollbar if that happens.

In the right part, I want to put google map with height that reaches certain margin above the bottom of the screen.

I've tried viewport height but when it has a navbar above the section I want the height to be viewport minus the height of the navbar (ex: 40px plus certain margin, say 10px below):

```
#left {
  height: 100vh - (40px + 10px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#right {
  height: 100vh - (40px + 10px);
}
```

Thus i want only #left will have a scrollbar. Is there a simple way to do this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kw4qLrgr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through JS by sizing your `div.container` and a little update to your css.

```
<script>   

 $(document).ready(sizeContent);

    $(window).resize(sizeContent);

    function sizeContent() {
        var height = window.innerHeight - 90; //90 = The size of your header minus margins 
        $('.container').height(height);
    };

</script>


#left {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Regards.